# Division with two integers returns value with wrong comma

Tags: php

I'm experience a strange problem on one of my customers sites:

```
$val1/$val2 = 0,123
```

Note the `,` in `0,123` as comma where it should be a dot `.`.

Is this a server setting which I don't know?

The `$val` are definitely integers but just in case -  this doesn't work too:

```
intval($val1)/intval($val2) = 0,123
```

PHP version is `5.4.43-1~dotdeb+7.1` on `Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)`

Comment: Probably you have some strange locale setting.

Comment: yea, thought so. What should I do? Do a `str_replace` for the only customer having that issue or forcing them to "fix" it. What should I tell them?

Comment: so um change the locale settings

Comment: Is their a "guid" why this is even possible? How to check via PHP for this?

Comment: The comma won't be present in the actual number, just in the output.

Comment: I do some calculation later in JavaScript which doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your locale is clearly set to something in which a decimal is represented by a comma.

To show the current locale:

```
var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, 0));
```

To show the current numeric formatting info:

```
var_dump(localeconv());
```

In order to avoid unintended changes to other localized bits of your code I'd suggest changing only `LC_NUMERIC` to your desired region. eg:

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US');
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php